# Android 4.1.1 ssl exception while accessing Nasa webservice

Tags: android, ssl, https, outputstream

I'm trying to access to a Nasa webservice, using Android 5.x everything works, but when using Android 4.1.1 an Exception is throw: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer

```
 OutputStream output = null;
            url = new URL("https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/text/Europe_24h.csv");
                HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                https.getInputStream(); <---- fails here
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site supports only TLS 1.1+, not TLS 1.0 (see the [analysis of SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov)).
Android 4.1.1 does not support TLS 1.1+ according to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=4.1.1).

Comment: Thanks! Tls 1.1 is not supported in Android 4.1.1.